# New to C#, listview

Tags: c#, listview, addition

When I go to run the program it is empty, no data displayed

```
namespace _0000003
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            soulpets = new ListView();

            ListViewItem lvi6001 = soulpets.Items.Add("6001");
            lvi6001.SubItems.Add("Tough Ent, Rare");
            ListViewItem lvi6004 = soulpets.Items.Add("6004");
            lvi6004.SubItems.Add("Stone Fist Ent, Rare");
            ListViewItem lvi6007 = soulpets.Items.Add("6007");
            lvi6007.SubItems.Add("Healing Ent,Rare");


            Controls.Add(soulpets);
```

Comment: You bound the event on the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, the code will be executed when you change the selection

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm to new at this to know what you are telling me to do to fix my problem, could someone fix the code so that I can see where I went wrong and learn from it, all the tuts i have found use a button to add data so in adapting that code I have messed up somewhere, I changed the soulpets = new Listview to soulpets.items.clear, no change, I feel that i need to tell it where to place the data but i don't know what is required, thanks guys @PhilippeParé

Comment: Hey @GrantWinney, could you please edit my code so that I can see, and learn the correct way to do this

Comment: No @GrantWinney it came up with errors, I couldn't run it

Answer (score 0):

```
soulpets = new ListView();
```

should be `soulpets.Items.Clear();`

You probably want:

> add a listview via the designer with the name `soulpets`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fillListViewSoulpets();
    }

    private void fillListViewSoulpets()
    {
        soulpets.Items.Clear(); //it should already be empty
        soulpets.Items.Add(
            new ListViewItem({ "Tough", "Ent", "Rare" }),
            new ListViewItem({ "Stone", "Fist", "Ent", "Rare" }),
            new ListViewItem({ "Healing", "Ent", "Rare" }) 
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much guys, like I said I'm very new to this, your help and advice is much appreciated.